# Parse data from teradata transactional table to another table using python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing, teradata

So I'm new in Python and I want to do some data parsing. I have a table in Teradata with millions of records. 1 column of table have the transaction description like our bank statement e.g (Purchase on 25/02 Amazon.com) and other column  has amount debited e.g (52)(let's forget the currency and only focus on number) and there are other columns which I don't want to consider for now.
I want to create another table with only 2 columns, merchant name and amount, which should look like:

Merchant Amount

```
Amazon    52
Amazon    96
Walmart   50
```

I can parse the data for single merchant at once but not for multiple merchant as I have more than 100 different merchants or even more

```
query= """select Merchant, Amt from Table1"""

df = pd.read_sql(query,conn)

for each in df:
    df1= each[each.Merchant.str.contains("AMAZON")]
    df1['Merchant']='AMAZON'
    total=df1.groupby(['Merchant'])
    print(total.head())
    break

df1.to_csv(r"Desktop\output1.CSV", index=False)

with open(r"Desktop\output1.CSV",'r')as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        insert = 'INSERT INTO Table2(Merchant,Amt) VALUES(?,?)'
        cursor.executemany(insert, row['Merchant'],row['Amt'])
```

Comment: Can you update the post with the DataFrame you have or at least few lines of data and what you have tried that will help others to guide you into right direction.

Comment: @pygo sample code updated

Comment: If you want to process data from a table in Teradata and insert it into a new table in Teradata, why don't you do it in Teradata? Can you show some examples of that `merchant` column, Is the logic always based on `contains`? Do you have a known list of merchants?

Comment: @dnoeth I tried with Teradata using wildcards but since there are millions or billions of record after running for 2-3 hrs, DBA are killing the process. Merchant could be the same as of your regular bank statement and merchant name is mentioned in middle of the string and comes after the date part,e.g("purchase on 25/02 Amazon abc def 123"), so merchant name always come after the date in the same string, some of the merchants are Amazon, Walmart, 7 eleven, McDonalds etc.

Comment: DBA will kill *you* when you export billions of rows and then insert back :-) You can use Regular Expressions, e.g. `RegExp_Substr(merchant,'\d\d/\d\d \K(.+?)\b',1,1,'i')`, which extracts the first name after the date (fails if there's no date and returns only `7` for `7 eleven`) or you use the known list of merchants `RegExp_Substr(merchant,'\b(amazon|walmart|7 eleven|macdonalds)\b',1,1,'i')`, the list can be up to the max length of a VarChar. This processes each row only once, of course there's some CPU usage

Comment: You should do as much as possible on TD side and use python only for extra logic. Substring or string search you can definitely check in TD. And I really do not recommend to loading data view single line insert statements. Use Fastload, bteq or TPT.